# Why I am encountering following error for below code :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java

Create a program that asks the user to input words until the user types in an empty String. Then the program prints the words the user gave.

Type a word:

Liszt

I have written following code but getting above error:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   String word = input.nextLine();
   ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println("Type a word: "+ word);

   while(word.isEmpty() == false)
   {
       words.add(word);
   }

    for (String wd : words){
        System.out.println("You typed the following words:");
        System.out.println( wd);
    }
```

Comment: You're not changing the value of `word` inside the while-loop; so when it enters the loop, it will repeat forever and add the same element to `words` until you run out of memory.

Comment: Can you show the line the error occurs on? Most likely this is the cause. You can also step through the code in your debugger to see why it isn't doing what you expect. Your `while` loop is very suspicious. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this part of the code:

```
   while(word.isEmpty() == false)
   {
       words.add(word);
   }
```

You are constantly adding `word` to the list `words` without changing the content of the `word`. Because of that, your application consumes all available memory and then crashes with OOM exception.

From the context of the code, I would assume that this is what you want to do:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

  while (input.hasNextLine()) {
   String word = input.nextLine();
   words.add(word);
  }

  for (String wd: words) {
   System.out.println("You typed the following words:");
   System.out.println(wd);
  }
 }
}
```